# How to use a Function within Anonymous Block?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

**Question**

I want to use a function **'calculate_bill_for_order'** i've created. I want to use it in my anonymous block. When I run the anonymous block the user should be prompted to enter a food order number **'orderno'** and then is should calculate food order total. The block I have created does not work and im not sure why.

**Annonymous Block**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET VERIFY OFF
ACCEPT total_order_no PROMPT 'Enter order number to calculate total'
DECLARE
total_order_no varchar2(6) := &total_order_no;
total integer;

BEGIN
  SELECT CALCULATE_BILL_FOR_ORDER(ORDER_CODE) INTO total
  FROM customer_order
  WHERE order_code = total_order_no;

END;
/
```

**Function**

Works fine

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_bill_for_order
    (order_code  IN  customer_order.orderno%TYPE) 
  RETURN number IS
    total_income number := 0;


  CURSOR food_order_cursor  IS
    SELECT dish.price, food_order.n_portions
  FROM food_order, dish
  WHERE food_order.orderno = order_code
  and food_order.dishid = dish.dishid;
  food_record food_order_cursor%ROWTYPE;


  CURSOR drink_order_cursor IS
  SELECT drink.price, drink_order.n_units
  FROM drink, drink_order
  WHERE drink_order.orderno = order_code AND drink_order.drinkid = drink.drinkid;
  drink_record drink_order_cursor%ROWTYPE; 


BEGIN
    OPEN food_order_cursor;
    LOOP
        FETCH food_order_cursor INTO food_record;
        EXIT WHEN food_order_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    total_income := total_income + (food_record.price * food_record.n_portions);
    END LOOP; 
    CLOSE food_order_cursor;


  OPEN drink_order_cursor;
    LOOP
        FETCH drink_order_cursor INTO drink_record;
        EXIT WHEN drink_order_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    total_income := total_income + (drink_record.price * drink_record.n_units);
    END LOOP; 
    CLOSE drink_order_cursor;
    RETURN total_income;
END;
/
```

***UPDATE***

Hey thanks for reply.
this is the errors I get:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET VERIFY OFF
ACCEPT total_order_no PROMPT 'Enter order number to calculate total'
DECLARE
total_order_no varchar2(6) := '&total_order_no';
total integer;
BEGIN
  SELECT CALCULATE_BILL_FOR_ORDER(ORDER_CODE) INTO total
  FROM customer_order
  WHERE order_code = total_order_no;

END;
/

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 7, column 9:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "ORDER_CODE": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 5, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
Elapsed: 00:00:00.031

**This is your code:**
enter code here
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 31:
PLS-00201: identifier 'O00001' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 16:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 4, column 30:
PLS-00302: component 'ORDER_CODE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 4, column 15:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 13, column 22:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 13, column 22:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "TOTAL_ORDER_NO": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 11, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 15, column 37:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 15, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 19, column 47:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 19, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
Elapsed: 00:00:00.031

**This is your code that I slightly modified:**

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET VERIFY OFF
ACCEPT total_order_no PROMPT 'Enter order number to calculate total'
DECLARE
total_order_no varchar2(6) := &total_order_no;
total number;
v_order_code  customer_order.orderno%type;
BEGIN
  SELECT ORDErno INTO v_order_code
  FROM customer_order
  WHERE orderno = total_order_no AND orderno = order_code;
  total := CALCULATE_BILL_FOR_ORDER(v_order_code);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('No such order' || total_order_no || ' - ' || sqlcode);
END;
/

Orderno is an attribute in Customer_order table AND order_code is a substitution used in calculate_bill_for_order function
```

Comment: Define "does not work".  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?  Are you seeing a behavior that you do or do not want?  If so, what behavior?  You're not doing anything with the `total` that you calculate in the anonymous block so the issue may simply be that you want to do a `dbms_output.put_line`.  But your problem may well be something else since you're not specific.

Comment: Normally I would specify order number  the order number in a simple select stament for example:
SELECT DISTINCT calculate_bill_for_order('O00001') as total_bill
FROM customer_order;

but in anonymous block i put ORDER_CODE instead of actual code 'O00001' because the user will be prompted to enter it

Comment: Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?  Are you seeing a behavior that you do or do not want? If so, what behavior?  Like I said, my first random guess is that your anonymous block doesn't do anything with `total`.  But if you're getting an error, telling us what error you're getting rather than making us guess would be very helpful.

Comment: Hey, I have updated my post. Have a look please

Answer (score 0):

you should post the error you are getting there, that will help us a lot to understand what is happening. 
However, trying to figure out what are you looking for and in my opinion this isn't the right way to perform that action. You could obtain the order first, and then inject that order to the function, and finally you'll have the total. Maybe this help:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET VERIFY OFF
ACCEPT total_order_no PROMPT 'Enter order number to calculate total'
DECLARE
total_order_no varchar2(6) := &total_order_no;
total number;
v_order_code  customer_order.order_code%type;

BEGIN
  /*I assumed you are looking for just one value
    and total_order_no is the value to perform the 
    searching of that order number */

  SELECT ORDER_CODE INTO v_order_code
  FROM customer_order
  WHERE order_code = total_order_no;

  total := CALCULATE_BILL_FOR_ORDER(v_order_code);

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('No such order' || total_order_no || ' - ' || sqlcode);
END;
/
```

Hope this help!!.